# What does internal mean in function names in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, naming-conventions, elisp

Some people use double dash to indicate that the function is subject to change: 
[What does the double minus (--) convention in function names mean in Emacs Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180390/what-does-the-double-minus-convention-in-function-names-mean-in-emacs-lisp)

Does including `internal` in function names mean similar things?

Two examples

```
where-is-internal
internal-make-var-non-special
```

The function `where-is-internal` has a detailed docstring and is mentioned in the manual as well. Is `where-is-internal` an exception?

Is there a difference between having `-internal` as suffix and having `internal-` as prefix?

Adding to confusion, there are also function names with `internal--` (with double dash) as prefix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion is not just in the naming convention (variability due to history and perhaps sometimes whim).  The confusion is in the very *notion* of "internal" in free software, where the source code is open to everyone to use or modify (even fork) as they please.

To answer your question from (what I think is) the point of view of Emacs Dev, and thus in terms of the underlying intention: "internal" means that someone using such a function is perhaps more likely to encounter future changes in the Emacs-Dev implementation and use of that function than might be the case for a non-"internal" function. IOW, you might not want to count on it remaining as it is now. That's all.

But there's a lot of "perhaps", "more likely", and "might" in there. In practice, some non-"internal" functions change more radically or more quickly than some "internal" functions.  It might be the case that for the former there will be a deprecation grace period, during which the pre-change situation is tolerated, i.e., still works. That might not be the case for something "internal". But again, in practice there is some gray between the black of "internal" and the white of non-"internal".

Someone from Emacs Dev (e.g. @Stefan) will perhaps put this differently or correct my interpretation.

My own take: there have sometimes (often) been functions and variables that the author did not expect users to make use of directly, and thus naturally thought of as "internal", which users have nevertheless put to good use, or even "had" to use (modulo rewriting lots of code).  Some such have had their "internal" status removed (no, I don't have examples memorized).  Or sometimes a new, non-"internal" function has been added to make the behavior available - e.g., a wrapper or function-valued argument has been added (again, I have no offhand examples to give).

IOW, for Emacs Dev too it is not always clear what should be considered "internal".  Just take the label as a flag that you might not want to count too much on that function or variable.

Wrt the various notations: My impression is that the `--` convention seems recently to be used more (though there is also some old code that uses it); using `internal` is an older convention, for the most part.

Comment: I disagree with your opening paragraph. Whether there's a distinction between internal and external functions is an aspect of the interface of a library, whereas whether it's free or open source software applies to its implementation.

Comment: 1. This is Lisp, not Java or C. 2. This is Emacs, an interactive, user-oriented program *intended (designed) to be actively customized and reprogrammed by users*. This is not Lisp code controlling a nuclear power plant. 3. One person's internal is another's useful-function-to-call-elsewhere. 4. The original author sometimes does not appreciate that a function s?he thought of as "only" internal, or "only" workhorse implementation stuff, can be useful elsewhere. 5. We can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 5):

The "internal" and the "--" conventions are similar.  Basically "internal" is used when there's no prefix after which to put a double dash (which is usually the case for functions implemented in C).

And yes, as Drew explains, the intention behind the notion of something being "internal" is just to recommend people not use it directly.  IOW if they need the corresponding functionality, they should report a bug requesting to promote its status to "non-internal".