# Emacs lisp namespace and internal function conventions

Tags: coding-style, package, naming-conventions, elisp, internal

In emacs the typical method of marking package namespaces is to choose
a (preferably short) prefix applied to all symbols related to the
package; In order to indicate that a function is considered "internal
use only" and shouldn't be used directly outside of the package the
most common convetions seem to be `prefix--functionname` and, or when
a function requires a very simple subfunction e.g.
`prefix-functionname-1`.

However, I also often need kind of "sub-packages", e.g. when a package
consists of several public functions that I have split into
non-overlapping subfunctions. Are there conventions whether to prefer

```
mypkg-list-all
mypkg-list-all--filter-list
mypkg-list-all--fontify-buffer 
mypkg-list-all-public-subfunction
```

or

```
mypkg--list-all-filter-list
mypkg--list-all-fontify-buffer
mypkg-list-all
mypkg-list-all-public-subfunction
```

?

Intuitively I find the first version better, since `--` here also acts
as kind of a "subpackage" delimiter and groups the most closely
related functions together in the completion buffer. Sadly it causes
the internal functions to be listed before the public functions of the
same hierachy level, which makes me question that convention.

Are there any convetions on this or is it just "everyone as they
want"?

Also, in many cases, particularily when the "fully qualified" name of
a function becomes lengthy, the lack of distinction between word and
package delimiter feels a bit problematic; personally I have found
myself using naming conventions like

```
mypkg-view-mode
mypkg-view-mode:mouse-action
mypkg-view-mode:keyboard-action
```

so I was wondering if there might be a better convention for subgroup
delimiters than the single hyphen `-`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is precisely a duplicate, but the following was asked only a few days ago, and certainly overlaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812352/what-does-internal-mean-in-function-names-in-emacs-lisp, along with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180390/what-does-the-double-minus-convention-in-function-names-mean-in-emacs-lisp which was already mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Colon as a symbol separator is, generally, discouraged (it makes it harder to [load emacs lisp into common lisp](http://clocc.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/clocc/clocc/raw-file/tip/src/cllib/elisp.lisp) and will probably interfere with a future emacs lisp package system).

Double dash (hyphen) `--` is used to indicate that [the symbol is internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180390/what-does-the-double-minus-convention-in-function-names-mean-in-emacs-lisp) to the package.

Thus the currently accepted practice is `package-external-symbol` and `package--internal-symbol`.

The official [Emacs Lisp Coding Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html) page does not talk about this issue in detail, just specifies:

> You should choose a short word to distinguish your program from other
>   Lisp programs. The names of all global variables, constants, and
>   functions in your program should begin with that chosen prefix.
>   Separate the prefix from the rest of the name with a hyphen, ‘-’. This
>   practice helps avoid name conflicts, since all global variables in
>   Emacs Lisp share the same name space, and all functions share another
>   name space.

Comment: So no convention at all for structuring names within a namespace? I also noticed that `org-mode`, particularily `org-babel` introduces many symbols that contain colons; Mostly language-specific implementations of functions, e.g. `org-babel-execute:C++`.

Comment: I don't myself ever loading Emacs Lisp into a Common Lisp environment.  But I *do* want a namespace prefix to be an *obvious* namespace prefix.  Readability counts, you know.  Thus, colon is my namespace-separating character.  If Emacs *EVER* gets proper namespaces (and I really don't see a chance in that, at least not in the non-distant future), I can rework whatever I need to.

Answer (score 2):

There's no accepted convention on this one.  I personally tend to use "pkgname-sub--internal" rather than "pkgname--sub-internal", probably because I don't pay much attention to how functions/varables get sorted.